# CSV date format changes after import into R

Tags: r, csv

I tried to import `csv` with date format:

```
3/1/2017 0:00
3/1/2017 1:00
3/1/2017 2:00
3/1/2017 3:00
3/1/2017 4:00
3/1/2017 5:00
```

into R, however the date format appears in R become:

```
2017-03-01 00:00:00 2017-03-01 01:00:00 2017-03-01 02:00:00 2017-03-01 03:00:00 2017-03-01 04:00:00 2017-03-01 05:00:00
```

How can I read `csv` into R as the original format without changing anything?

Comment: That is how R prints a timestamp vector. Your other option is to read it in as a text string (you can use the `colClasses` argument of `read.csv`), but then it will just be a string, rather than a nice datetime object that R knows what to do with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the "original" format, in the sense that you're probably looking at a `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt` object. You can reformat dates and datetimes using `format()` or `strftime()`, but this will render them character.

So as long as you're working with the datetime objects, just leave it as is. If you need to report, you can use any of the aforementioned functions to format the string:

```
x <- "3/1/2017 3:00"
x1 <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
x1
# [1] "2017-01-03 03:00:00 CET"

strftime(x1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
# [1] "03/01/2017 03:00"

format(x1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
# [1] "03/01/2017 03:00"
```

Comment: Your advice works, but after I reformat using as.POSIXct, I found it showed NA if I use: as.POSIXct("2017-03-12 02:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"). as.POSIXct("2017-03-12 03:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") works. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @Jonnce The format I used in `as.POSIXct()` is your original format. In your data it is already in a POSIXct or POSIXlt format (you can check with `class()` ). The format in `as.POSIXct()` is the input format of the string, whereas in `format` and `strftime` it is the output format.

Comment: Oh I got it, thanks. But I still got NA when I run:  as.POSIXct("03/12/2017 02:00:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") can you please help me figure out what's the reason?

Comment: @Jonnce I copy-pasted that in my R console and I got a correct result. So for me it works. If it's really not a typo, you should ask a new question and include the information of your operating system. The interpretation of dates and times is not done by R but by the operating system itself. So it can differ depending on whether you run Windows, Mac or a linux flavor

Comment: Megs Thank you very much for format argument of input & output, Yes the problem of 2:00:00 is because of timezone.

Comment: Hi Joris, I think the downvote is for the question not for your answer. Your answer is great.